# Tarski's conception of truth for formulas of infinite length

Tags: logic, truth, semantics

Does Tarski's semantic conception of truth, in particular, his convention (T) (X is true iff p), extends to formulas of infinite length?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but just want to point out - which I'm sure you know - that Gentzen used formulas upto e_0 to prove the consistency of arithmetic.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - [Gentzen's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) use induction up to epsilon_0 as axiom in the metatheory.

Comment: Yes; see [Infinitary Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/) and [Tarski's Truth Definitions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/#195DefOff) : "Already in the 1950s model theorists were interested in formal languages that include kinds of expression different from anything in Tarski's 1933 paper. Extending the truth definition to infinitary logics was no problem at all."

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of infinite expressions (formulas, strings, words): 1) Those which can be described by finite expressions, and 2) those which have an infinite complexity and cannot be reduced to finite expressions.

Examples of the first in the domain of real numbers are 0.111... or SUM(1/n!). These expression are precisely defining numbers as their limits, and analogous logical expressions can be used too.

Examples of the second kind are most of the real numbers because there are uncountably many but only countably many finite expressions. These surplus numbers are undefinable and therefore cannot have a numerical value that could be communicated in mathematical discourse. Same is true for infinite sequences of logical atoms or other infinite expressions. They cannot have a truth value because every truth value obtained up to a certain step could be negated in the next step. Without an "End Of File" there is no value discernable.

Comment: The counting argument is a common misconception: [it *is* possible that every real number can be specified uniquely by a formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084138/is-it-possible-that-every-set-can-be-specified).

Comment: What's going on is directly analogous to the fact that the turing machine acceptance problem is not decidable -- there does not exist a set expressing the relation that a given (internal) real number satisfies a given (internal) formula. (assuming I've not made an error)

Comment: @Hurkyl: Yours is a common misconception (which also Cantor adhered to). A formula is a finite sequence of letters over a finite alphabet. There are only countably many such formulas. See Weyl: "The possible combinations of finitely many letters form a countable set" or Bernays: " if we pursue the thought that each real number is defined by an arithmetical law, the idea of the totality of real numbers is no longer indispensable" or Kurt Schütte:  "If we define the real numbers in a strictly formal system, ... then these real numbers can certainly be enumerated". Or enumerate them yourself.

Comment: Why should there be a set that gives an enumeration? Incidentally the same phenomenon happens in the theory of computation: we just use the term "recursively enumerable" rather than "countable".

Comment: @Hurkyl: Why should there be a set that gives an enumeration? Because all formulas belong to an enumerable set. (You can also call it recursively enumerable.) Therefore mathematics tells us that there are not enough formulas for the real numbers.

Comment: I wasn't asking why there should be a set enumerating formulas, I was asking why that -- together with the hypothesis that every real number can be given by a formula -- should imply there exists a set giving an enumeration the reals.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, surely you conceive of the notion pairs (P,r) where P is a predicate, r is a real number, and r is the only object in the set theoretic universe satisfying P. The question is why there should be a set of all such pairs.

Comment: We must be careful. *r* is not a real number but an expression that can be substituted by a real number. For that sake you have to define the number that you want to use. You cannot define it however if it has an infinity of digits without a formula allowing to obtain every digit.

Comment: I don't see why, to introduce a variable of type real number, one would need a formula for the digits (that's not even a good notion in computable analysis!), but one is available: the digit in place n is the remainder of floor(|r| / 10^n) when divided by 10.

Comment: The question is *not* to introduce a variable. The question is whether every real number can be defined, The answer is: If there are uncountably many real numbers, then most of them cannot be defined, because different real numbers require different definitions, but there are only countabl,y many definitions. - Sorry, this is basic knowledge. I will stop here.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a *common* misconception. Cardinality can be conceived as a measure of complexity just as well as a measure of size -- I advise understanding things in terms of the former if the latter misleads you.